# Escoger un numero o nombre al azar de una base de datos

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo alojada una base de datos `MySQL` en un `Byethost` gratuito necesito llamar del registro un nombre y o numero al azar para así generar un sorteo.

Con éste código logro llamar mis registros en `Javascript` ahora necesito que me llame un numero o nombre al azar.

```
function leer() {
    urltorequest = urlWS + "Usuario/leer";
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: urltorequest,
        async: false,
        success: function (respuesta) {
            toshow = JSON.parse(respuesta);
            cabeceraTabla = "<table class=\"table table-condensed\"><thead><tr>
                      <th>ids</th><th>Nombre</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
            pieTabla = "</tbody></table>";
            contenidoTabla = "";

            $(toshow).each(function (key, value) {
                contenidoTabla = contenidoTabla + "<tr><td>" + value.idUsuario + 
                "</td><td>" + value.nombreUsuario + "</td></tr>";
            });
            document.getElementById("respuesta").innerHTML = cabeceraTabla + 
            contenidoTabla + pieTabla;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Y qué has intentado ? o en qué fallas ?

Comment: Aún así, para lograrlo deberás obtener la cantidad total de nombres, y generar el número aleatorio con el algoritmo clásico en js

Comment: Aun no se que función añadir al la fución leer  o como hacerlo para que me devuelva solo un numero o un nombre

Comment: Bueno, si lo que quieres es elegir a una sola persona **no conviene transportarlas todas al lugar de la elección**. ¿Si estás en Canadá y tienes que seleccionar una entre 10,000 personas que están en Australia qué harías, traerías a esas 10,000 personas a Canadá pagándoles los billetes de avión, seleccionas a una y luego les pagas el billete de vuelta a Australia a las 9,999? Puedes hacerlo, pero es posible que quedes en la quiebra y en el manicomio después de hacerlo. Quiero decir con esto que es mejor hacer la selección en la base de datos y traer al seleccionado, y no traer a todo el mundo

Comment: ... para luego hacer la selección. [Estudia esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4329447/5587982) y también [este post](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/) que trata con bastante amplitud el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Imaginemos que esto viene de tu database:

```
$db_names = ["Christian", "Eduardo", "José", "Patricia", "Jacinta", "Muriel"]
```

Lo cual serían todos los nombres en tu database.

Entonces, debes obtener el largo de los nombres , en este caso al ser un array:

```
$db_names.length // 6 nombres´
```

Y el clásico algoritmo para generar números aleatorios es este:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximo - minimo + 1) + minimo)
```

`Math.floor()` redondea al menor entero, mas cercano al número.

`Math.random()` Genera un número entre `[0, 1[`

En este caso:

El máximo numero es el *número de nombres* = 6

El minimo es 0 , porque el array comienza desde el indice 0

Entonces podrás preguntarte, pero si comienza en índice 0, entonces podría salir el índice 6 y ese índice no existe en el array. Correcto , pero recuerda que el +1 hace que el valor `máximo`, sea inclusivo, osea que pueda ser generado, entonces NO le sumaremos 1, para que nos genere un número del `[0, 6[`

```js
var $db_names = ["Christian", "Eduardo", "José", "Patricia", "Jacinta", "Muriel"],
        random = (max, min, inclusive) => inclusive === true ? 
        Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min) :
        Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min),
    
        nameSelected = $db_names[random($db_names.length, 0, "false")];
    
   
        console.log(nameSelected);
```